# How to solve "Call to undefined function dbase_open ()" error in linux server?

Tags: php

Call to undefined function dbase_open () in php... While executing in local server (Xampp) it works fine.. But when i try to use in live project that is uploaded to website, in linux server it shows "call to undefined function dbase_open"...

Please tell whether any dll extension must be enabled in server or provide any solution to solve this problem....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Off-topic: System administration questions belong on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

check if `extension=php_dbase.dll` line is uncommented in *php.ini* as i remember it's commented by default

Comment: since he's on a linux server that would probably be `extension=dbase.so`

Comment: @Gryphius, you are right! im on win at the moment and this is copypaste. sorry :)

Comment: Yeah i've already uncommented extension=php_dbase.dll line in php.ini... but it does get work

Comment: i've also uncommented "dbase.so" but still doesn't work....

Answer (score 1):

depending on your distro you'll have to install some additional package. for example on centos/rhel you'd install it by running

```
yum install php-dbase
```

and then restarting your webserver

Comment: I've already installed php_dbase and restarted... My problem is dbase_open () works in local server but doesnt in web server